# Not able to click on dropdown elements with Selenium python for react UI

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to click on checkboxes but giving below error when tried.

How to proceed for clicking on checkbox?

Selenium Code:

```
def active_time(self, card_id, screenshot_path):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60, LINK_TEXT='Dashboard').click()
        self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                         XPATH="//li[starts-with(@class,'nav-item')]//button[contains(., 'RH') and contains(., "+str(card_id)+")]").click()
        print("Clicked on card" + str(card_id))
        self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60, XPATH="//button[contains(.,'Table View')]").click()
        print("Clicked on Table View")
        self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                         XPATH="//div[@class='dropdown-heading']/div[@class='dropdown-heading-value']").click()
        print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
        checkboxe1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("located checkboxes")
        print(len(checkboxe1))
        print(checkboxe1)
        checkboxe1 = checkboxe1[1]
        print(str(checkboxe1))
        checkboxe2 = self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60, XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']//span[contains(.,'ACTIVE TIME')]")
        time.sleep(5)
        if checkboxe1.is_selected():
            print("All checkboxes selected")
            checkboxe1.click()
            print("Unchecked All items from dropdown")
            if checkboxe2.is_selected():
                print("Active is Selected")
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                print("Took Screenshot")
                checkboxe1.click()
                print("Selected all items from dropdown")
            else:
                print("Active not selected")
                checkboxe2.click()
                print("Selected active time")
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                print("Took Screenshot")
                checkboxe1.click()
                print("Selected all items from dropdown")
        else:
            print("All checkboxes not slected")
            checkboxe1.click()
            print("All checkboxes selected")
            checkboxe1.click()
            print("Unchecked All items from dropdown")
            if checkboxe2.is_selected():
                print("Active is Selected")
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                print("Took Screenshot")
                checkboxe1.click()
                print("Selected all items from dropdown")
            else:
                print("Active not selected")
                checkboxe2.click()
                print("Selected active time")
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
                self.get_element('element_to_be_clickable', 60,
                                 XPATH="//div[@class= 'item-renderer ']//input[@type = 'checkbox']").click()
                print("Clicked on table-view drop down")
                print("Took Screenshot")
                checkboxe1.click()
                print("Selected all items from dropdown")
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        self._result = "FAIL"
        raise AssertionError('%s:' " Click on active time is failed" % (self._result))`
```

Error after running  above code:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'click' in selenium python

HTML:

```html
< div class = "panel-content" > <div class="select-panel" role="listbox">
    <ul class="options">
        <label class="select-item " role="option" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
            <div class="item-renderer ">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1">
                    <span>Select All</span>
                </div>
            </label>
            <li>
                <label class="select-item selected" role="option" aria-selected="true" tabindex="1">
                    <div class="item-renderer ">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" checked="">
                            <span>STATE</span>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label class="select-item selected" role="option" aria-selected="true" tabindex="2">
                        <div class="item-renderer ">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" checked="">
                                <span>IPV4 ADDRESS</span>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="select-item selected" role="option" aria-selected="true" tabindex="3">
                            <div class="item-renderer ">
                                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" checked="">
                                    <span>IPV6 ADDRESS</span>
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </li>
```

Comment: post your selenium code as well. one line is not enough.

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius   Attached Selenium code as well

Comment: whats the line youre getting stuck on? and please format the code correctly. Mark it and click ctrl + K

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to find all the checkboxes and click on each checkbox:

```
#find all the checkboxes
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox"]')


#iterate through all the checkboxes and click on each checkbox
for checkbox in checkboxes:
    checkbox.click()
```